# How to post a correct request to express route using axios?

Tags: express, axios

I use axios to update a document by id, but my `POST request` sends incorrect data to backend.

Here is an express route:

```
    router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const updatedPost = await Data.updateOne(
          { _id: "5d28a6fcec97b111c2f5867d" },
          {
            $set: {
              phone: req.body.phone,
              email: req.body.email,
              title: req.body.title,
              longTitle: req.body.longTitle,
              introTitle: req.body.introTitle,
              introLongTitle: req.body.introLongTitle,
              videoLink: req.body.videoLink,
              introText: req.body.introText
            }
          }
        );
        res.json(updatedPost);
      }
      catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
      }
    });
```

This is a fragment of a React component that handles a form and requests (I did not show all the code, since other parts works. If necessary, I'll show all the code):

```
    const data = {
      "phone": this.state.phone ? this.state.phone : this.state.data[0].phone,
      email: this.state.email ? this.state.email : this.state.data[0].email,
      title: this.state.title ? this.state.title : this.state.data[0].title,
      longTitle: this.state.longTitle ? this.state.longTitle : this.state.data[0].longTitle,
      introTitle: this.state.introTitle ? this.state.introTitle : this.state.data[0].introTitle,
      introLongTitle: this.state.introLongTitle ? this.state.introLongTitle : this.state.data[0].introLongTitle,
      videoLink: this.state.videoLink ? this.state.videoLink : this.state.data[0].videoLink,
      introText: this.state.introText ? this.state.introText : this.state.data[0].introText
    };

    axios.post('http://localhost:5555/data', {data})
      .then(res => {
        console.log(data);
    })
```

When I type some texts in inputs and submit the form, `console.log` shows an object with the same. But after checking the data with `GET request`, it shows `NULL` fields in `JSON`. I tried to use `JSON.stringify({data})` in axios request, but it does'nt help.
Maybe someone know, what is incorrect.
Thanks for any help!)

Comment: Assuming you have `body-parser` or equivalent, your data should be accessible under `req.body.data['YOUR_PROPERTY']`. This is because you sent your data using `axios.post('http://localhost:5555/data', {data})`, which translates to `req.body = { data: { ...form data } }`.

Comment: Do you know where the issue is? If you're getting the updatedPost in the response, why do you think the *request* is wrong?

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!
I use body-parser, and U are right!
It works when i change to:
$set: {
          phone: req.body.data.phone,
          email: req.body.data.email,
          title: req.body.data.title,
          longTitle: req.body.data.longTitle,
          introTitle: req.body.data.introTitle,
          introLongTitle: req.body.data.introLongTitle,
          videoLink: req.body.data.videoLink,
          introText: req.body.data.introText
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Axios request to:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5555/data', data)
    .then(res => console.log(data));
```

Your use of object shorthand is creating an additional level in your data object:

```
// If you do
axios.post('http://localhost:5555/data', {data})

// Express will receive it as
req.body = {
    data: {
        phone: ...,
        email: ...,
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, if Express is hosting your client and API, you can change your Axios request to:

```
axios.post('/data', data)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        // Do stuff with updated post here
    })
```